# Having trouble with PHP bind_param() with an UPDATE

Tags: php

Hi i am new to php and i am having trouble with bind_param. i have been trying for hours with no luck.

here is my code:

```
  $username="username";  
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT AdminID#, UserName, Password, Salt FROM AdminMembers WHERE  UserName = ? LIMIT 1");
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $username); // Bind "$username" to parameter.
  $stmt->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.
  $stmt->store_result();
  $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt);


  echo $user_id;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $username;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $db_password;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $salt;
```

i get a blank screen.

any one can see if i have something wrong with my code?

Comment: you have an error in your sql query

Comment: Any error? Use[`$stmt->error`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.error.php) or [`$stmt->error_list`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.error-list.php), print on the screen, and show to us, please.

Answer (score 0):

USE **backticks**

```
SELECT `AdminID#`, `UserName`, `Password`, `Salt` FROM AdminMembers WHERE  UserName = ? LIMIT 1
```